# How to spatially separate rug plots from different series

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to graphically evaluate distributions (bimodal vs. unimodal) of datasets, in which the number of datapoints per dataset can vary widely. My problem is to indicate numbers of data points, using something like rug plots, but to avoid the problem of having a series with many data points overhwelm a series with only a few points.

Currently I'm working in `ggplot2`, combining `geom_density` and `geom_rug` like so:

```
# Set up data: 1000 bimodal "b" points; 20 unimodal "a" points
set.seed(0); require(ggplot2)
x <- c(rnorm(500, mean=10, sd=1), rnorm(500, mean=5, sd=1), rnorm(20, mean=7, sd=1))
l <- c(rep("b", 1000), rep("a", 20))
d <- data.frame(x=x, l=l)

ggplot(d, aes(x=x, colour=l)) + geom_density() + geom_rug()
```

[image]

This almost does what I want - but the "a" points get overwhelmed by the "b" points.

I've hacked a solution using `geom_point` instead of `geom_rug`:

```
d$ypos <- NA
d$ypos[d$l=="b"] <- 0
d$ypos[d$l=="a"] <- 0.01

ggplot() + 
  geom_density(data=d, aes(x=x, colour=l)) +
  geom_point(data=d, aes(x=x, y=ypos, colour=l), alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

However this is unsatisfying because the y positions must be adjusted manually. Is there a more automatic way to separate rug plots from different series, for instance using a position adjustment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way would be to use two `geom_rug()` calls - one for `b`, other for `a`. Then for one `geom_rug()` set `sides="t"` to plot them on top.

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x, colour=l)) + geom_density() + 
  geom_rug(data=subset(d,l=="b"),aes(x=x)) +
  geom_rug(data=subset(d,l=="a"),aes(x=x),sides="t")
```

[image]

Comment: This works great for two groups but I wonder if there is a simple way of stacking rugs three or more groups, such as [here](https://d2mvzyuse3lwjc.cloudfront.net/images/WikiWeb/Rug_Plot/Distribution_Curve_with_Rug.png?v=10549)?