# Overlay Plotly-like violin and rug plots

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, violin-plot

I am trying to create a plotly-like violin and rug plot using seaborn in python (Example: [plotly-like violin and rug plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi9Iz.png))

I am able to overlay rug plot on the violin plot and this is what I've come up with so far: [Seaborn attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRDGa.png). This was made using the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white")
sns.violinplot(data=[consp, intsp], scale='area', scale_hue=True, bw=.2, cut=1, linewidth=3)
sns.despine(left=False, bottom=True, top=True)
sns.rugplot(consp, height=0.05, axis='y', color='b')
sns.rugplot(intsp, height=0.05, axis='y', color='g')
```

However, I am wondering if it's also possible to spatially separate rug plot from different columns and overlay them next to respective columns like in the plotly example?

There is a similar question previously addressed for ggplot2 in R by setting sides for two separate geom_rug calls but it seems the solution provided isn't applicable to seaborn. (Previous question addressing a similar issue in R: [How to spatially separate rug plots from different series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16402560/how-to-spatially-separate-rug-plots-from-different-series))

Thank you for your help.